# Misra warning C code - Comparison of boolean and unsigned values in if loop

Tags: c, if-statement, boolean, misra

In the below C code, while checking the if condition, i am getting the Misra warning as

```
The operand of the opeartor '=='do not have same essential type category: one is 'Boolean' and other is 'unsigned'
```

In the header file `file1.h`

```
#define timer_4sec       (uint8)160
#define bool_rolltime    (roll_time_count < timer_4sec)
```

in the source file , `file1.c`

```
static uint8 roll_time_count = timer_4sec

void function()
{
  if(bool_rolltime == True)
  {
     printf("rolling ..\n");
  }
}
void function2()
{
    //update the roll_time_count status , increment and decrement static timer variable.
}
```

The problem is here `if(bool_rolltime == True)`. I have understood that `roll_time_count` and `timer_4sec` are `uint8` variables. So i have tried to fix this warning like this way

```
#define bool_rolltime    (bool)(roll_time_count < timer_4sec)
```

Is this code correct method to avoid the Misra error? If not please suggest how to avoid such warnings ?

Comment: Make `True` an `int` of value `1` ... or omit the `== True` part (`if (bool_rolltime) /*stuff*/;`)

Comment: OT: regarding: `if(bool_rolltime == True)`  True actually has the value of 1,  The macro might not return 1.  Suggest: `if(bool_rolltime != False)`  or even better: `if(bool_rolltime)`

Comment: `if(bool_rolltime)`

Comment: @user3629249: all relational operators yield an `int` with value of `0` or `1`. ([C11 6.5.8p6](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.5.8))

Comment: Why are you even comparing it to `True`?  It's already a truth value.  You just need `if (x)`, not `if (x == True)`.

Comment: A `0` value is false, all other values are true. For example `if(apples) { eat(1); }`

Comment: i want to know , `if(bool_rolltime == False)` is a valid statement ?

Comment: Not according to MISRA. You are comparing apples with oranges. Consider `if(bool_rolltime == True)`. When `bool_rolltime == 2` and `True == 1` then the equality test fails.

Comment: You have to remember that C (at least pre-C2x) has a real bodge as a boolean... a uint8_t with values 0 and 1 pretending to be a boolean.  Never check `== TRUE` as this misses 254 valid true values!  Always check `!= FALSE`

Comment: @Andrew would MISRA warn about that too?

Comment: But I'm puzzled as to why you are hiding your check in a macro... `if ( roll_time_count < timer_4sec )` is much clearer... although `if ( roll_time_count < ROLL_TIME_EXPIRY )` would be better, with `#DEFINE ROLL_TIME_EXPIRY TIMER_4SEC`

Comment: @Andrew No, `x != FALSE` is not enough, you need at least `(x != FALSE) != FALSE`, but I recommend `((x != FALSE) != FALSE) != FALSE` just to be super extra sure. This should cover 98% of all your boolean checking needs.

Comment: :-) N1... for booleans, you can of course just do `!x` - but this should only be done with booleans, and not non-booleans...

Comment: @Andrew "this should only be done with booleans" is incorrect.

Comment: @andrew and @weather Vane `#define bool_rolltime    (roll_time_count < timer_4sec)` will this return either `true` or `false` ? or `1` or `other values` since it is integers. which one is correct understanding ? if i make `bool temp = (roll_time_count < timer_4sec) ` then `temp` will return `true` or `false` . right ?

Comment: Yes... but why do you need the intermediate step?  Just do `if (roll_time_count < timer_4sec) `

Comment: @WeatherVane Of course, C allows boolean operations for non-boolean values, but MISRA does not allow this, and a static code analysis with MISRA rules (or a compiler with integrated MISRA checks) will complain.

Comment: The C Standard allows lots of things that are not necessarily a good idea ;-)

Comment: @Bodo yes thanks. I thought the comment was a more general statement.

Comment: Please show us the definition of `True`.

Comment: Does the code use `#include <stdbool.h>`? This would define a type `bool` and the constants `true` and `false`, not `True`. Where does the definition of `True` come from? If your intention is to define your own Boolean type and constant values, your MISRA checker might know only the definitions in standard include files.

Answer (score 2):

This essentially the same question you asked yesterday. As I answered then, you need to tell your static analyser which types that are boolean. Such as `bool`, `false` and `true`. Why you are using some home-brewed standard `True`, I don't know, but it's not a good idea as you noticed. Similarly, drop home-brewed `uint8` and use standard C `uint8_t`.

In addition, you get MISRA violations because of smelly macros hiding simple expressions. That's plain bad practice, MISRA or no MISRA. You shouldn't invent some mysterious macro language. Just keep it simple and readable:

```
#define timer_4sec       160u // no need for cast but you need the u suffix for MISRA-C

static uint8_t roll_time_count = timer_4sec;

void function (void) // empty parenthesis is obsolete C, write (void)
{
  if(roll_time_count < timer_4sec)
  {
     printf("rolling ..\n");
  }
}
```

Now that we kept the code simple and readable, it automatically turned MISRA-C compliant too. Both operands of `<` are of the same "unsigned" essential type category thanks to the 'u' suffix.

Again, like I already answered yesterday, you need to study the rules for essential type in the MISRA-C guidelines or you won't understand a thing of what the tool keeps telling you.